# Is there an "aptly" for yum

Tags: yum, package-managers

I have to set up a local yum repository that I can manage.

I'd prefer it have a way to make mirrors, snapshots, and publish the snapshots.

In the `apt` world, I use `aptly`, which does the above.

**Q: Is there something similar for `yum` packages?**

Comment: No, there are no such single package that can handle everything from repo creation and management. `yum` works well with  `createrepo` that is used for repo creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SpaceWalk, which does this and more: https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall

Comment: Spacewalk repository archived Jun 3, 2020.